# How do I type a array that has a mix of number and object (named array)

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this sample code:

```
const arr = [320, 480, 1024];
arr.small = arr[0];
arr.medium = arr[1];
arr.large = arr[2];
```

`console.log(arr)` will output:

```
[320, 480, 1024, small: 320, medium: 480, large: 1024]
```

What would be the type (interface on typescript) of `arr`?

note: It might seem weird, but it's common on a design system theme file, where you want support by scale or by naming.

Comment: node.js says `typeof arr` is 'object'

Comment: you have to use `{ small: 320 }` Not `small: 320` respecting the JSON syntax of course

Comment: I mean yeah, arr is a object, technically all array are object, but what would be the type or interface of it

Comment: @YasserCHENIK no, you don't have to... it's call associative array, it's legit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend `Array`:

```
interface MyArr<T> extends Array<T> {
  small?: T
  medium?: T
  large?: T
}

const arr: MyArr<number> = [320, 480, 1024];
arr.small = arr[0];
arr.medium = arr[1];
arr.large = arr[2];
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CCUoB4AqAfMhAB6QgAmAzstlHOgcQN4BQyy1AtnADZ8A-AC5k%20Dsm4RKwAK7cRYiXzhQA5hEXiAvmzYIA9iGphkqqKIz1cIeQCNoxALzIA2gGYATAAYANMgAWAA4-ZABGb08AgF0AbjZzADoefj5kF3NXbziEnESpGXl0sxxXMJyklXUUDNLPHKA)

I assume you could make the properties required if you need to, in which case you probably would create a normal array first and then extend it with the additional properties via `Object.assign`:

```
interface MyArr<T> extends Array<T> {
  small: T
  medium: T
  large: T
}

const arr = [320, 480, 1024];

const extendedArray: MyArr<number> = Object.assign([...arr], {
  small: arr[0],
  medium: arr[1],
  large: arr[2],
})
```

Alternatively if you don't actually need access to array methods, you can create an object with an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures):

```
interface MyObj<T> {
  [index: number]: T
  small: T
  medium: T
  large: T
}
```

Comment: Do you favor this advice over creating a new class that has an array and has small, medium and large props?  My intuition would be that, for readability, if no other reason.

Comment: @danh: Only if access to array methods is needed. It really depends on the concrete use case. Otherwise, a generic object with the same properties (`0`, `1`, `2`, `small`, `medium`, `large`) would work just as well.

Comment: I like this, I simplified a bit the code for question.  what if the "sizes" are already a type call `SpaceSizes`? I tried `export type MyArr<T = number> = SpaceSizes<T> extends Array<T>;` but I get a error 1005 expecting a '?'

Comment: I updated your playground a bit https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAymCGBjCMCWAvCBnAPAFQD4oBeKAbwCgoosBbeAGwYC4o8BuKqWiAE1QCutVhy4N4AJwDmEEZwC+FCqgB2wCBIBmSaAFkQAQQkT8RCAA91K3lihGJ8EKfJc6jBgH4RXHvyFe2MUkZALwKRQpQSCh9ewAmZ1I4HTRMXEIoCysbO2NHU04KRAB7FSxgKEkJVljjBJUhACMNIlIAbQBmOIAGABooABYADj6oAEZuuIGAXU4qgDo3JhJK4zbu2YoF30FaFaq2sc2F8WloUgO4zaA

Comment: @Yichz In that case you need an intersection type: `type MyArr2<T> = SpaceSizes<T> & Array<T>;`

Comment: @FelixKling unfortunately that doesn't work either. it errors with "number[] is not assigned to SpaceSizes<T>, conjunction `|` also doesn't work. see https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAymCGBjCMCWAvCBnAPAFQD4oBeKAbwCgoosBbeAGwYC4o8BuKqWiAE1QCutVhy4N4AJwDmEEZwC+FCqgB2wCBIBmSaAFkQAQQkT8RCAA91K3lihGJ8EKfJc6jBgH4RXHvyFe2MUkZALwKRQpQSCh9ewAmZ1I4HTRMXEIoADI7Y0dTTgpEAHsVLGAoSQlWWOMElSEAIw0iUgBtAGY4gAYAGigAFgAOXqgARi64-oBdTkqAOjcmEgrjVq6ZinnfQVplytbRjfnxaWhSfbiNoA

Comment: @Yichz: You get the error because you are trying to assign a new array to that special type. That cannot work because you cannot define the additional properties using the array at the same time you are declaring the array. It works just fine if you create the array separately: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAymCGBjCMCWAvCBnAPAFQD4oBeKAbwCgoosBbeAGwYC4o8BuKqWiAE1QCutVhy4N4AJwDmEEZwC+FCqEhQAsiACCEiQCZ8RUnCQoM2A1ABkUbRPggDnCogD2AOyzAoqN2AFfSKABtAGZdAAYAGigAFgAOKKgARnDdGIBdTlcPL0kJVg1bfTchACMICUMoAHlSgCsIRGAAOngsLFQpNwAKHz9gaMpqOkYWb19-IPD0yK4efiFWPsmkmbFJGSWJ4CDdNfkASiA

Comment: @Yichz: You can also create a helper function: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAymCGBjCMCWAvCBnAPAFQD4oBeKAbwCgoosBbeAGwYC4o8BuKqWiAE1QCutVhy4N4AJwDmEEZwC+FCqEhQAsiACCEiQCZ8RUnCQoM2A1ABkUbRPggDnCgDMBAO0TBUAezdREEhDwwBAatgYAFKhuYALAIgDaALoAlKxhOvqE5FyBwAISfgDyAEYAVhCeAHTwWFioUm5RMXEANDnU1HSMLFDRscAJAAxJrVzUPPxCrP1xCQCMo+NQ4tKyfS2DukvU8ikUihSIvljAUJISJNQBQSEZEhEJAMy6Q+0ALAAcb1DzQ7rvVIUIA

Comment: @FelixKling looks like I can do Partial + what you suggested before, so I can modify the type. thanks for the help. Do you see any downside of this? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAymCGBjCMCWAvCBnAPAFQD4oBeKAbwCgoosBbeAGwYC4o8BuKqWiAE1QCutVhy4N4AJwDmEEZwC+FCqgB2wCBIBmSaAFkQAQQkT8RCAA91K3lihGJ8EKfJc6jBgH4RXHvyFe2MUkZALwKRQpQSCh9ewAmZ1J7R2cAMigABUlgVEYcOB00TFxCAk4KRAB7FSxgKEkJVljjBJUhACMNIlIAbQBmOIAGABooABYADhGoAEZBuLGAXU4GgDo3JhJ64x7B5Yo130FaLYaemf218WloUjO4-aA

Comment: @Yichz: Yes, `Partial` works (it's equivalent to my first suggestion). As long as your code handles the optional properties properly I don't see a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The best type description of this array would be like this

```
type element = number | Object
type mixArray = element[]
type Two = {twoId:number, value:string}

const oneItem:mixArray = [320, 480, 1024, {small: 320}, {medium: 480}, {large: 1024}]
```

You can add more specificity to the Object and it would be like this

```
type elaborateElem = number | {small?: number, medium?: number, large?: number}
type elaborateMixArray = elaborateElem[]

const arr2:elaborateMixArray = [320, 480, 1024, {small: 320}, {medium: 480}, {large: 1024}]
```

[Play ground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBBA2EFsIDthQLxWQVwQIwgCcoAfKAeTwCsIBjYAKFEigQEsAPAQUMIEMQGGPCSoA2gF0G02gHtkAZzR9eARgBc7brwFCxAZgBMABgA0UACwAOM1FXHDF8wG8FCPrFjqoR4wF8XJAATNlxva38XWBUAcwhve0c-KWlmaAVIWjYPShp6IWc-JnBoOD48WX5gCABRESEcfCJSKFd3TwB%20b0aCQnNg0IQurFxe82jCOOGeoiK04XLKvmqAWU4efkFMMoqq2pFJGXklKBVCQ3UdpdX1nS2oAxNzCPNEp1a3Dy8fEwDWgbClhsf2cEziCQcFmS0mkQA)

I would really recommend using [Zod](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod) in your typescript to help in organizing such issues and to help you in type managment